# While loop inside of while loop

Tags: php

I'm running a while loop to display all images under a path;

```
<?php
    $files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $root = "http://www.rafflebananza.com/";
        $imagePath = $files[$i];
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imagePath);
        $imageName = str_replace("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/", "", $withoutExt);
        echo '<div class="UploadedImgs">
                <div class="ImgName">'.$imageName.'</div>
                <div class="IMG">
                    <img src="'.$root.$imagePath.'" alt="Random image" />
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
?>
```

What I'd like to now happen is a maximum of 8 images to show and add a button at the bottom going from 1 to X, wrapping each 8 in a div I'll set to be hidden and set the links at the bottom as the tab switchers.

How do I run an additional while loop passing vars back and forth?

**Almost there!**

```
<?php
    $files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");
    echo '<div class="Wrapper">'; //First tab
    $t = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $root = "http://www.rafflebananza.com/";
        $imagePath = $files[$i];
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imagePath);
        $imageName = str_replace("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/", "", $withoutExt);

        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            $t = $t + 1;
            echo '<div id="Tab_'.$t.'" class="Tabs"><h1>Tab_'.$t.'</h1>'; //hidden class
        }

        echo '<div class="UploadedImgs">
                <div class="ImgName">'.$imageName.'</div>
                <div class="IMG">
                    <img src="'.$root.$imagePath.'" alt="'.$imageName.'" />
                </div>
            </div>';

        if( $i > 0 && $i % 7 == 0 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            echo '<a href="'.$t.'" class="tab-switcher">'.$t.'</a>';
        }
    }

    echo '</div>'; //closes last div
?>
```

The CSS

```
.Wrapper .Tabs:nth-child(n+2) {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it, and then see where you're having problems?

Comment: `$imageName = pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Comment: Well I would not have done what @Skatox has posted as an answer, I would have wrapped in a loop, however it still appears my initial problem still is there how to detect if $i is a multiple of 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve it with **mod operator**: `%,` if a number is divisible by 8, then you have 8 images. So you can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");

    echo '<div class="UploadedImgs">'; //First tab
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $root = "http://www.rafflebananza.com/";
        $imagePath = $files[$i];
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imagePath);
        $imageName = str_replace("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/", "", $withoutExt);

        if( $i % 8 == 0 )
            echo '</div><div class="UploadedImgs hidden">'; //hidden class

        echo '<div class="ImgName">'.$imageName.'</div>
                <div class="IMG">
                    <img src="'.$root.$imagePath.'" alt="Random image" />
                </div>
            </div>';

        if($i % 8 == 0)
            echo '<a href="#" class="tab-switcher">Change tab</a>'; //link to change tab
    }

    echo '</div>'; //closes last div
?>
```

Comment: `if( $i % 8 )` How do I do a multiple of 8? My knowledge is not great right now but this appears to only make two divs? I'll add more files to this locations to actually test soon, just woke up!

Comment: I just thought, maybe if ($i / 8 does not have decimal) {

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake it's actually (!$i % 8) because the modulo of the division will be from 0 until 7 (remember division rules), so if a number is divisible by 8, it will return 0 then the ! will make it positive and will enter to the if. You can resume the i%8==0 with !$i%8. More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Does the if statement not need to be enclosed with { } ? Still learning, not seen this before :)

Comment: Please see updated question. How would I set `echo '<div id="Tab_'..'">';` to Tab_1/2/3/4/5?

Comment: Nice! You don't need braces because i only want to execute the line after the if, if you need the div tab, then just  have a number increasing at the second if.

Comment: Updating now, still broken a bit :/

Comment: Viewing source shows only one image goes into the surrounding container. Just made a [liver version](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/example.php) for you to see.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen my comments @Skatox would appreciate some feedback?

Comment: Ah, figured where the problem is! The second if statement with the closing div... Now to figure out how to solve...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69148/discussion-between-skatox-and-tim-marshall).